# Reuse ftp connection in Clojure using clj-ftp

Tags: clojure, ftp

I am trying to fetch files from FTP server using Clojure. I would like to download all files using one connection. I am using https://github.com/miner/clj-ftp/blob/master/src/miner/ftp.clj clj-ftp for this. Unfortunatelly I am unable to achieve it with one connection. Got two functions:

```
(defn one-session [files]
  (ftp/with-ftp [client ftp-url]
    (map #(ftp/client-get client %1)
         files)))

(defn get-all [files]
  (map #(ftp/with-ftp [client ftp-url]
          (ftp/client-get client %1))
       files))
```

When calling `get-all` everything works fine. When trying call `one-session` I got exception `NullPointerException   org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.getRemoteAddress (SocketClient.java:658)`

I noticed that in `clj-ftp` there is a lot of type hints, does it have inpact on it?

Whole stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/private/var/folders/4d/77tz4xfj7b1dkqtd3h4j10v40000gn/T/form-init2973639134882885374.clj:1:125)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.getRemoteAddress(SocketClient.java:658)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:789)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1854)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1845)
    at miner.ftp$client_get.invokeStatic(ftp.clj:144)
    at miner.ftp$client_get.invoke(ftp.clj:138)
    at miner.ftp$client_get.invokeStatic(ftp.clj:140)
    at miner.ftp$client_get.invoke(ftp.clj:138)
    at zephyr.fetch$one_session$fn__1296.invoke(fetch.clj:30)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__4785.invoke(core.clj:2644)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:521)
    at clojure.core$seq__4357.invokeStatic(core.clj:137)
    at clojure.core$print_sequential.invokeStatic(core_print.clj:46)
    at clojure.core$fn__6072.invokeStatic(core_print.clj:153)
    at clojure.core$fn__6072.invoke(core_print.clj:153)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:233)
    at clojure.core$pr_on.invokeStatic(core.clj:3572)
    at clojure.core$pr.invokeStatic(core.clj:3575)
    at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3575)
```

Comment: Could you show the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked the source of the ftp library and it seems that you have to realise the lazy sequence created by `map`. Otherwise, the call to `ftp/client-get` is executed after leaving the `with-ftp` block when the elements are fetched from the result sequence and at that time the created connection has been already closed.

To fix the problem you need to force the realisation of the sequence using [`doall`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall):

```
(defn one-session [files]
  (ftp/with-ftp [client ftp-url]
    (doall
      (map #(ftp/client-get client %1)
           files))))
```

This will force all `ftp/client-get` calls to happen within your `with-ftp` scope.

On the other hand it might not be desired to realise all the sequence at once as it might have dangerous consequences (e.g. memory utilisation). You might read more on Clojure lazy seqs mixed with side effects in [Stuart Sierra's blog post](https://stuartsierra.com/2015/08/25/clojure-donts-lazy-effects).

In your particular case `ftp/client-get` returns `boolean` value indicating if the file download to a local file was successful or not so it is not a big issue. In other cases you might redesign your API so your function accepts not only a seq of files but also a function which encapsulate what you want to do with each file and apply that function to each value as it is consumed one by one without keeping the whole sequence in memory. @Frank Henard made a valid point that you could use `doseq` for that.

Comment: I like `doseq` for side effecting loops.

Comment: Is it also possible to use `pmap` in such combo? I am trygin to it hangs after 2 seconds. Tried also direct `future` call but i blows memory.

Comment: It depends if the API you are using is thread safe. In this case you need to check if `FTPClient` can be used concurrently from multiple threads.